# How to shut down a local instance of Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Last week I started a local instance of azure service fabric and was able to play with the nodes and services on my machine locally. Visual studio set up a cluster and I figured that it would close on shutdown. Today I'm having an issue where FabicGateway.exe and Fabric.exe are running on my computer in the background. These still persisted when i deleted the applications from the Service Fabric Explorer at my local host address.

How do i shut down the service fabric so that it doesn't run in the background at my computers startup? Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of the SDK? I believe they fixed this in the newest release of the SDK (6th of May 2016), version [2.0.217](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/05/06/release-of-service-fabric-sdk-2-0-217/)
. In the release notes they state:

> **The FabricHost service was incorrectly marked as autostart for local development clusters which would cause the cluster to be restarted on reboot, and resetting or re-creating the local development cluster would reset FabricHost to autostart mode.**
>   This would lead to local resource consumption and was frequently undesired for the local cluster environment. Changes were made to support non-autostart for local development environments and not to override user choice here.

otherwise you can use the manager to close a cluster. The manager is located at: *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager*

Comment: Its funny that the update for this came out only just 3 days ago. I preformed both of these actions and my problem was solved. Thanks for the quick response!